# Vb.net Owin Owin.FormCollection to MVC.FormCollection Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, owin, webapi

```
    Dim owinCollection As Object
    context.OwinContext.Environment.TryGetValue("Microsoft.Owin.Form#collection", owinCollection)

    Dim grantType = (CType(owinCollection, FormCollection))?.GetValues("grant_type").FirstOrDefault()
```

Hi
I want convert owinCollection to Form Collection but im getting error. How can i fix it ?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do it?  I would expect, based on the error, that the specific conversion you ask for is impossible, so the best path forward would be to find an alternative that still accomplishes your ultimate goal.

Comment: I solved this but now it returns nullPointerException